# Display last added user in mysql database on PHP page

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, rows

I am not really good at coding, and don't know how I should call this.

I have made something to register, it saves the users to the mysql database. Now I want to make a php script displaying the last added user.

I'm currently using this script, but it keeps displaying 0.

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('hedery');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (users) values ('username')");
printf("Last added user: %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
?>
```

The database name is"hedery". The table is "users". And inside the users there is " id  username    password    email   activated   banned  firma"

Now I want to display the last added "username".
Would be nice if soemone could tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks alot to the stackoverflow community btw. This site got me so far already..

Comment: `mysql_insert_id()` returns `id` - which is number.

Comment: Oh oops! Do you know what I can change to display the last added username?

Comment: Use query to select `username` with order by id desc.

Comment: $result = mysqli_query(username) or something like this? Sorry but I'm really bad at this ;(

Comment: I have this now, but how to I get the lastest? {$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `username` FROM `users` ");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
echo $row}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('hedery');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (users) values ('username')");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mytable` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['username'];
?>
```

Comment: How can I display it as text? Like i want to show the username.